# gdb - Prevent losing backtrace in a catch/rethrow situation

Tags: c++, exception, gdb

Is it possible to re-throw an exception without losing the back-trace in gdb?  Or is there a way in gdb to "back up' a few lines and back trace from there?  I'm on GDB 7.7.1, the most recent.

I sometimes find myself running into situations like this, needing a back trace from the original throw of the exception, and needing to comment out the try/catch parts, recompiling, and re-running in gdb.

```
try {
   someFuncThatCanThrowException();
} catch(exceptionType& exception) {
   if(@CAN_RECOVER@) {
      ...
   } else {
      throw;
   }
}
```

----OR----

```
try {
   someFuncThatCanThrowException();
} catch(exceptionType& exception) {
   exception.printMessageToCout();
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> needing a back trace from the original throw of the exception,

Is it OK to use a simple approach of printing all backtraces of all throws and then when it is necessary to find a backtrace of a particular exception just find it by the address of the exception. Something like this sequence of gdb commands:

```
set pagination off
catch throw
commands
info args
bt
c
end
```

When you need to find backtrace of an exception, first print its address, like this:

```
print &exception
```

And find its address in the gdb output. It must be printed by `info args`. As soon as you find address there will be backtrace of this exception after `info args` output.

Comment: There's a bit more discussion of the "catch throw" command in this question, which I think is in fact the right approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592568/can-gdb-be-used-to-backtrace-when-exceptions-are-caught